# Can you explain this Python list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
def get_max(r, a, b):
    """ Returns the maximum value in the form (index, value). """
    return max([(x+a, r[a:b][x]) for x in xrange(len(r[a:b]))], key=lambda x:x[1])
```

Can anyone explain what this list comprehension does?

Comment: This is a good example of why readability counts when coding.

Comment: It means that whoever wrote this code didn't know about `enumerate`, and didn't really understand `for` loops.

Comment: `max(enumerate(my_list[start:end],start),key=itemgetter(1))` would do the same thing and is more clear to me... not sure why this function even exists

Comment: at least it's documented... somewhat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For efficiency it's a good idea to avoid repeating the slice of `r` over and over

```
chunk = r[a:b]
[(x+a, chunk[x]) for x in xrange(len(chunk))]
```

I think it also makes the meaning of the code a bit clearer (it's not exactly Pythonic) yet

```
chunk = r[a:b]
[(i, j) for i, j in enumerate(chunk, a)]
```

Oh it's the identity list comprehension

```
list(enumerate(chunk, a))
```

so instead of all that waffle, you can say

```
def get_max(r, a, b):
    """ Returns the maximum value in the form (index, value). """
    return max(enumerate(r[a:b], a), key=lambda x:x[1])
```

as @vonPetrushev tries to explain in the comments, you can replace the lambda function with an itemgetter.

```
from operator import itemgetter
def get_max(r, a, b):
    """ Returns the maximum value in the form (index, value). """
    return max(enumerate(r[a:b], a), key=itemgetter(1))
```

There isn't much performance difference and the `itemgetter` version is more descriptive (as long as you know what `itemgetter` does)

Comment: Great! I would also encourage the use of `itemgetter` - even though it would mean importing from `operator`, it will clear up the lambda occurence, and also, we can clearly define the key function outside `get_max`:

    `from operator import itemgetter
    key1 = itemgetter(1)
    def get_max(r, a, b):
        return max(enumerate(r[a:b], a), key=key1)`

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down into pieces.

First, here's just the listcomp on its own:

```
[(x+a, r[a:b][x]) for x in xrange(len(r[a:b]))]
```

That's equivalent to this loop:

```
result=[]
for x in xrange(len(r[a:b])):
    result.append((x+a, r[a:b][x]))
```

So, what does each part do?

`r[a:b]` is the sub-sequence of `r` from index a (inclusive) to b (exclusive). So `len(r[a:b])` is almost a fancy way of saying `b-a`, but not quite—because `b` could be past the end of the sequence, or either one of the indices could be negative indices. And `xrange(len(r[a:b]))` is just all the numbers from 0 up to that length (again exclusive).

Now, for each of these numbers `x` from 0 to that length, we create a tuple `(x+a, r[a:b][x])`.

Let's work through an example:

```
>>> r = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> a = 2
>>> b = 4
>>> r[a:b]
['c', 'd']
>>> len(r[a:b])
2
>>> list(xrange(len(r[a:b])))
[0, 1]
>>> x=0
>>> (x+a, r[a:b][x])
(2, 'c')
>>> x = 1
>>> (x+a, r[a:b][x])
(3, 'd')
```

So, as you can see, it's creating a list of (index, value) for the indices from `a` to `b`, like this:

```
[(2, 'c'), (3, 'd')]
```

---

A much nicer way to write the same thing is:

```
>>> list(enumerate(r))[a:b]
[(2, 'c'), (3, 'd')]
```

… or …

```
>>> list(enumerate(r[a:b], a)
[(2, 'c'), (3, 'd')]
```

Comment: Amusingly, while the original code does work for stuff like `(r,1,-1)`, it returns the wrong index when you have a negative `a` (like `(r,-8,-3)`).

Answer (score 1):

`r` is a sequence, `a` is a starting index, and `b` is an ending index.  The list comprehension will give a list of `(index, r[index])` tuples where `a <= index < b`.  The `max()` call will then return the tuple with the largest value (second item in the tuple).

Comment: Actually, if someone passes in `(r, 1, -1)` then your simplified version doesn't work.

Comment: Plus, this is still pretty hard to read. There's no reason to avoid calling `enumerate`…

Comment: Good point, removed the alternate version so the answer is now just the explanation.  Other answers that use `enumerate` cover alternatives well.